# How to customize seaborn.scatterplot legends?

Tags: seaborn, legend

I plotted a scatterplot with seaborn library and I want to change the legend text but dont know how to do that.

example:
The following is iris dataset with species columns encoded in 0/1/2 as per species.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
pl = sns.scatterplot(x='petal_length', y ='petal_width', hue='Species', data=data, s=40,
                palette='Set1', legend='full')
```

[image]

I want to change the legends text from [0, 1, 2] to ['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'].
can anybody help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, Seaborn (and Matplotlib) usually picks up the labels to put into the legend for `hue` from the unique values of the array you provide as `hue`. So as a first step, check that the column `Species` in your dataframe actually contains the values "setosa", "versicolor", "virginica". If not, one solution is to temporarily `map` them to other values, for the purpose of plotting:

```
legend_map = {0: 'setosa',
              1: 'versicolor',
              2: 'virginica'}

plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = sns.scatterplot(x=data['petal_length'], y =data['petal_width'], hue=data['species'].map(legend_map), 
                     s=40, palette='Set1', legend='full')
plt.show()
```

[image: iris dataset scatterplot]

Alternatively, if you want to directly manipulate the plot information and not the underlying data, you can do by accessing the legend names directly:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = sns.scatterplot(x='petal_length', y ='petal_width', hue='species', data=data, s=40,
                 palette='Set1', legend='full')
l = ax.legend()
l.get_texts()[0].set_text('Species') # You can also change the legend title
l.get_texts()[1].set_text('Setosa')
l.get_texts()[2].set_text('Versicolor')
l.get_texts()[3].set_text('Virginica')
plt.show()
```

This methodology allows you to also change the legend title, if need be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!! I tried many other things before but didn't worked out.

Comment: what if I want to delete 0th text. how to do that. I tried to ```set_text('')``` but it leaves a blank line which I don't want.

Comment: Yeah the locations in the legend are fixed by then, so you cannot just remove it. One trick is to plot each "Species" (or category) on a separate ax, and when you get to the one you want to omit in the legend, specify `label='_no_legend_'`. As a shortcut, you can map that species/category to a name that starts with an understore, and by convention it will not show up in the legend: `legend_map = {'setosa': '_setosa', 'versicolor': 'versicolor', 'virginica': 'virginica'}`